# Corruption at end of GZIP files when using MultipleOutputs in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, gzip

I am compressing the output of a Hadoop MR job with:

```
conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
TextOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(conf, true);
TextOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(conf, GzipCodec.class);
```

I am using MultipleOutputs like:

```
MultipleOutputs.addMultiNamedOutput(conf, "a", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(conf, "b", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(conf, TextOutputFormat.class);
```

Separately, each of these work great. I can get the division of outputs I want and I can have gzipped output.  However, when using these together, the gzipped files appear to be corrupted at the end.  Each output file has around 25000 lines.  When I do something like

```
hadoop dfs -cat output/*.gz | less +24000
```

everything looks normal.  But if I do

```
hadoop dfs -cat output/*.gz | less +40000
```

I get errors such as

```
zcat: stdin: invalid compressed data--crc error
zcat: stdin: invalid compressed data--length error
zcat: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
```

If I repeat the first command and start scanning through the file, eventually I encounter one of the above errors after an incomplete line or several very long, very corrupted lines (I presume they are long because the newline characters have also been corrupted) and `less` can go no further.

So, my question is: has anyone seen this before, and is there a way to fix it?

Note: I am using the mapred API instead of mapreduce. I can try to translate to the new API, but if I can find a solution using mapred, that would be preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply a guess (without seeing your reducer code), but are you calling `MultipleOutputs.close()` (on the instance of MultipleOutputs, rather than a static method, which doesn't exist) in the cleanup method of your reducer?

It looks like the final block of the gzip files are not being written - consistent with not calling the above method

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!  I completely overlooked that part of the usage pattern in the docs for MultipleOutputs.  It works great now.